# HTML A Name attribute on android browser

Tags: android, html

I have a web page with about 150 HTML `<a name="blah"></a>` elements, plus 26 more that group these by letter, like `<a name="lettera"></a>`.

The page passes W3C HTML validation and renders and operates correctly in desktop browsers.  Trying two different Android browsers and an emulator, the letter index does not work. When any letter is selected, the page only moves to the `lettera` tag. The location bar correctly shows `<site>page.htm#letterx` as the current location, but the display has not moved.

Other pages on the same site with a smaller number of name tags work correctly. I found one web reference saying that some browsers did not like to see two name tags in a row and suggesting placing the nonsense tag  in between them to break them up, but this did not help. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case it helps someone else someday, it appears there needs to be actual renderable content between two successive name tags for the android browser (a comment alone didn't do it). When I added some all worked as intended.